# Cstrings in C++

Tags: c++, cstring

why this code gives the wrong output?? Output is 5 and 9, shouldn't it be 5 and 4. 
Here is the code

```
int main
{
    char a[10] ={'a','b','c','d','e'};
    char c[] = {'q','t','y','t'};
    cout<<strlen(c)<<endl<<strlen(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. #include <cstring>
2. add NULL terminator for each string

Comment: you are missing terminating zeroes.

Comment: You can better do `char a[10] = "abcde";` It will assign the terminator for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour, because you're calling `strlen` with a pointer to a character array that is not null-terminated (`c`). You need to pass null-terminated strings for this to work. This is an example, fixing that and some other errors, and including the required headers:

```cpp
#include <iostream> // std:cout, std::endl
#include <cstring>  // std::strlen

int main()
{
    char a[10] ={'a','b','c','d','e'};  // OK, all remaining elements 
                                        // initialized to '\0'.
                                        // Alternative: char a[10] = "abcde"

    char c[] = {'q','t','y','t', '\0'}; // or char c[] = "qtyt";

    std::cout << std::strlen(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::strlen(a) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the `a` array value-initiialized to 0 for the remaining elements?

Comment: @ComicSansMS Yes, that is right, good catch. I will fix that.

Comment: I would add the other option of `char a[10] = "abcde"` and `char c[] = "qtyt"`

Comment: `int main` is also a bug

Comment: @marcinj Thanks, I had missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

`c` needs a null character at the end for `strlen` to work.

You can use

```
char c[N] = {'q','t','y','t'};
```

where `N` is 5 or greater.

or

```
char c[] = {'q','t','y','t', '\0'};
```

or

```
char c[] = "qtyt";
```

to add a null character at the end of `c`.